# Slick Slider Autoplay not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I have implemented [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for my webpage. The swiping works just fine, and the images show one after the other. The only problem I'm having is getting the slider to initiate `autoplay` when the page finishes loading.

[Here's](http://alynxagency.com/success-stories/luxury-brand.php) link to my page.

HTML

```
<div class="single-item insideslideshow slider autoplay slickplay">
    <div class="eachsliderimage" style="background-image: url('images/real-estate/2.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="eachsliderimage" style="background-image: url('images/real-estate/1.jpg'); "></div>
    <div class="eachsliderimage" style="background-image: url('images/real-estate/3.gif'); "></div>
    <div class="eachsliderimage" style="background-image: url('images/real-estate/4.jpg'); "></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.single-item').slick({
      draggable: true,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      touchThreshold: 1000,
  });
    $('.autoplay').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add the script you use for your slick slider please?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for the heads up. I posted some of the code, there is a lot of additional code in external css and script files. Let me know if I should find any of it and add it to the main post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not setting `autoplay` on your `.single-item`

If you change your JavaScript to the below code, it will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.single-item').slick({
          draggable: true,
          autoplay: true, /* this is the new line */
          autoplaySpeed: 2000,
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          touchThreshold: 1000,
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hahaha @Gael, you are too quick ;) thanks for editing it out for me :)

Comment: and the one who edited the question was more faster :)

Comment: @Frits Why is it necessary to also include it in that section of the code?

Comment: @AlexBanman I've actually edited my answer. You were initiating slick slider twice. Once on an element called `.single-item` and once on an element called `.autoplay`. This is actually what slick use in their example, you had to make sure that the autoplay field was set to the `single-item` function because your site doesn't have a set of element called `autoplay` and you can actually remove that from the code :)

Comment: If it helps you understand it even better, when you call `$('.single-item').slick({ ........ });` you are actually telling your slick script that you are creating a slider from the children items of an element with the class `single-item` and that the parameters/settings are what you are including in between the curly brackets - does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was puzzling over your last comment! I see what you mean now by calling it twice. I was telling the slick script that the relevant code was contained in the .single-item parameters, so it was ignoring the .autoplay code... is that right? 

I guess this code is a little bit advanced, experienced coders would know right away what to do there. I'm just throwing code around and hoping it will work out.

Comment: Hahaha I'm far from experienced, I just happen to play with slick every now and then, in the end, we all just play :) That's not exactly what happened, it's more that there was no element with the class `.autoplay` so it ignored the second initialization. Good luck with the rest!

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. Thanks again!